# Why am I recieving a segmentation fault in my heapify/find min program?

Tags: c, heap

I am coding a program that will take an array, heapify it, then find the kth smallest element. From my textbook I was able to get a lot of the algorithms needed down, but I am stuck now, because I am receiving a segmentation fault whenever I attempt to test the program.
In the textbook in the struct it has PQ_SIZE as size of q, but I could not figure out why or how to make that work, so I made it 6 because the n I have been testing with is 5, however whenever I compile the program then enter 5 as my first number, I receive a segmentation fault even though it is less than 6. I am just in general confused and any advice at all regarding my code would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So debug it. If you don't know how to use a debugger add some `printf()s` so you can see where things start to go wrong...

Comment: Your indices are off by one as far as I can tell. It is traditional to represent heaps with one based indexing. The actual implementation  has to use zero based because that's just how C arrays work.

Comment: Why would you remove your code from the question. Part of the idea of SO is that we all learn from others' mistakes. Now if somebody comes to this question, they won't be able to see your code, and the supplied answer makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `main()` you passed `*heap` which is uninitialized pointer to `pq_init()` where you are assigning value to its member

```
 priority_queue* heap;
 pq_init(heap);
```

This is going to lead undefined behaviour, you need to allocate memory to `heap` prior to using it

Comment: There are other issues but this is likely the one causing the segfault.

Comment: Thank you very much, that actually ended up working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually compiled the posted code?

One of the warning messages output by the compiler is that the `priority_queue *heap;`  is being used uninitialized.

Specifically, the pointer is passed to the function: `pq_init()`.

the function: `pq_init()` dereferences that pointer for the field `n`.

However, the pointer: `heap` has not be assigned to some area in memory that is owned by the application  (a call to `malloc()` would fix that).  As it is, the pointer `heap` contains where trash happens to be on the stack where the pointer is located.

Note: the definition of the struct `priority_queue` does not have a `tag` name.  This lack of a tag name will be a problem when using a debugger to step through the program.

====

Variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `i`, `j`, `q`, `p`, `x` etc are meaningless, even in the current context,

====

the code should follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

====

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.
2. separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite novice still. Thank you very much though for your detailed response.